# Getting my data off of a G2 with a broken screen

Tags: backup, data-recovery, broken-screen

I have a T-mobile G2 (aka HTC desire Z) with a broken screen. I have not rooted it or ever enabled debugging.

I would like to get the data off of this phone and onto my replacement. Is there any way to do that? The phone doesn't even show up when I run `adb devices`.

(My pictures are on the sdcard, so they're okay. I'd like to get my other application data off though. Especially SMS history and some notes from a memo application.)

Is there any method I can go about to do this?

Comment: Other questions you might want to check: [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/), [Broken Screen + Using adb shell to run vnc server](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19317/), [How do I backup data (sms/contacts) from a device with a broken screen ?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25646/). At least one of them should prove helpful ;)

Comment: I looked at those questions before. Most of the answers require you to have rooted your phone previously. http://android.stackexchange.com/a/23928/19271 Does not seem to require it, but it presumes more than I understand right now.(CWM recovery image -- Where do I get that? CWM appears to require having been previously installed, but that's not entirely clear.)

Comment: CWM stands for [ClockworkMod](http://www.clockworkmod.com/), and usually is installed via the [ROM Manager](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager) (`.apk` available on that site or via playstore). While you could probably install this `.apk` via ADB, you run into the chicken-and-egg problem trying to install CWM with it. There should be flashable images available (see [CyanogenMod Wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/TMobile_G2:_Rooting) for download and full instructions).

Comment: chicken-egg is right. Right now, I can't even get the phone to show up under `adb devices`.