# Is there any technique for controling a smart phone over another smart phone ( both are android)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, remote-access

As because one of the phones display is damaged throgh some part.
If there is any method please tell me....

Comment: You might wish to check with [Broken Screen + Using adb shell to run vnc server](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19317/16575) and the questions linked to that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Teamviewer or Webkey. Teamviewer is only supported by selected Samsung phones, and Webkey requires root, though. If your phone is not supported by Teamviewer, you are most probably not going to achieve anything without rooting the phone you want to control. (Android only allows an app to inject screen taps and grab the screen in special circumstances: if the app is signed with the manufacturer's key (Teamviewer does this, so it doesn't need root) or the app is running as root.)

Comment: Trouble with both might be: Won't you have to start the "server" part on the damaged device? If so, how can that be done if there's no working touch-screen?

Comment: I think Webkey's "server part" can be started via ADB.

Comment: Just need to find out *how*. Maybe similar to [Broken Screen + Using adb shell to run vnc server](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19317/16575), if one knows the name of the corresponding activity.