# Cracked Screen CM13 Rooted VNC

Tags: adb, root-access, vnc

I cracked the screen on my LG G3 running CM13. It's rooted but I can't get to a adb root shell because ADB root is not enabled by default. I want to clean up some stuff and VNC is my best bet. I installed VNC Droid Server but I can't click on Start to get it started. Instructions [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19317/broken-screen-using-adb-shell-to-run-vnc-server?newreg=506d6c27ae554061a8903ea021f6bd4e) require root over adb to start the vncserver manually.

**Does anybody know how I can get a VNC server started on Android 6.0 without the ability to touch the screen?**

Answer (score 0):

Vysor is the answer! It's a Chrome app with a built-in VNC server that launches automatically. It even works on Android 6+. Find it [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwibseqC_-HPAhUEWT4KHYciBwgQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fvysor%2Fgidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm%3Fhl%3Den-US&usg=AFQjCNE-OAnF4O44DcCZNPj70kZVOe8bJw).